# What do you think about optional as prefix to protobuf field names?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

Since `proto3`, the protobuf spec got rid of the `optional` and `required` fields. Now the only way to find out if a field in the message is optional only by looking at the docs, which is not very convenient. How about we use `optional_` as the prefix on the field name for optional fields.

#### Without `optional_` prefix:

Protobuf

```
message User {
    string user_id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string email = 3;
}
```

Code

```
# Don't know which fields are optional, we have to check the docs:
user.user_id = 1
user.name = "bob"
user.email = "bob@gmail.com"
```

#### With `optional_` prefix:

Protobuf

```
message User {
    string user_id = 1;
    string optional_name = 2;
    string optional_email = 3;
}
```

Code

```
# it is more informative but doesn't read naturally in English.
user.user_id = 1
user.optional_name = "bob"
user.optional_email = "bob@gmail.com"
```

I have not usually seen optional fields named like that. It was used in one of my past teams and it was very convenient. Do you have any particular opinion on this?

Comment: Honestly, "I need to look at the docs to use an API for a remote service" sounds like a win to me... but: this is entirely subjective. Do what works for you and your team.

Comment: Looking at the docs to be able to understand semantics of the remote service call sounds great but this is more on just the field level where I have to go check for each field if it's optional. Imagine a protobuf with tens of fields. Not only the author but also the reader of the code who is reading on Github.

Comment: well, obviously they can just point to their working integration tests that show the service working on the test account...

Comment: Do you expect all authors (while modifying the code) and readers (trying to understand the code) of the consumer code to read integration tests of the remote service?

Comment: nope; but I *would* expect the integration tests to *get run at some point*, whether that is manual or via CI, to indicate unanticipated failures; the same as anything else